# Colorize Image Texture with Nodes

Tags: materials, node-editor, shader-nodes

I have imported a leaf from the plugin "Grove" into a Blender file and want to give the leaf a new color. Strangely, the Images Texture does not respond to anything I do. I also tried to completely reconnect the Material Output. All this seems to do nothing.

I would like to colorize the leaf as it is seen on the Images Texture but keep THE SHAPE OF THE LEAF. Around the leaf you can see the orange geometry of the plane, but it is much rougher. As always, thanks for your very helpful tips!

[Blend File](https://we.tl/t-6Ti3CvxEnU)

[image: Nodes]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The material of the leaf is called *Blaetter*. Put a *Hue/Saturation* node just after the *Image Texture* that has *PaperBirchFallTop.png*, like that, and play with the values:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Christoph, it looks like you've created a second *Material Slot* for this object.

[image]

The material that is applied to the faces of the mesh is probably in slot 1, and may be why none of your changes are being reflected - even when disconnecting the *Material Output*.

Caveats: This material *does* have 8 users, which would mean that potentially every leaf you've created has this second slot.  OR this could also be a copy of the same material in slot 1, in which case your changes *should* be reflected *everywhere* regardless of the extra slots.

But if that were the case I'd have serious questions about what kind of crazy RGB node you're using, there.